# Django: Custom validator function

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Contract class in my model. A contract can be related with a person or with another contract which is an extended contract of a previous one. All good so far.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Name"))
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Surname"))
    address = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Address"))

class Contract(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person) #person hired
    contract = models.OneToOneField('self', blank = True, null = True) #allows to extend a contract
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank = True, null = True) #related project
```

So, in the Admin interface, when I want to extend a contract I put the name of a person and the field contract shows me all the contracts in the data base. What a I need is that when I put a person the field contract only shows me the contracts of that person.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's not a validator.

Comment: You can do it with Javascript/jQuery. See the selected person, then make an Ajax POST call to an URL of the API which you`ll define and retrieve the contracts of that person. Then populate the dropdown box only with these contracts

Comment: @MihaiZamfir do you know where I can find some info about that? It'd be the first time I do something like this. Thanks!